# Returning variables in the view function for django and ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, templates, variables

I need to populate an element with data from two variables depending on what the user selects from a list of choices. I have a view function that gets the table id from post (does it have to be post?) and returns additional information about that id from the table. So I need to get the two variables somehow from my view function to the template. The problem is how should I return it? by httprequest, render, or render_to_response and do I use the same template that I used to send the ajax data? I have seen tutorials that just returns httpresponse with one variable and no template, which just confuses me more than anything. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends what you want to do with the data in the Javascript code that receives it.

One option is just to return JSON via HttpResponse. Then your JS can process it and create HTML elements as necessary.

An alternative is to use a template fragment which just renders the bit you want: the advantage of doing that is that you can use the familiar template syntax to build up the HTML as usual, and all your JS has to do is to insert it into the existing page at the appropriate point.

And no, it doesn't need to be POST: in fact GET would be better semantically here, because you're not actually making changes to stored data.

Comment: if i do pass in json data then in my ajax function will the success function have data paramenter be the json data? As in success: function(data) {...}

Comment: Whatever you return, whether it is JSON, rendered HTML, or anything else, will be accessible as that parameter.

Comment: K, i will write the code and see what happens. Will accept answer afterwards. Thanks.

Comment: k i did it, but I used post, since get adds something to the url, which was giving me an url parsing error. So I did post.